# package java.util.regex does not exist (codenameone)

Tags: java, regex, netbeans, codenameone

I'm building an application in Codenameone (Java) and need a quick email check with regex.
But now for some reason whenever I build my app I get the error that the java.util.regex package does not exist.
Netbeans gives no errors when compiling and I can access the sourcecode from all the classes in java.util.regex but for some reason netbeans can not find it when building.

I did some searching on the web but could not find anything of use.
I use Netbeans 7.4 and JDK 7 (JRE 1.7.0_51)

This is the code for the mail check:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

protected boolean checkMail(String email) {
    String EMAIL_PATTERN
            = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
            + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    return matcher.matches();
}
```

This is the error i get:

```
F:\Pantera\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TherapieApp\src\be\pantera\TherapieApp\RegisterPage.java:25: error: package java.util.regex does not exist import java.util.regex.Matcher;
F:\Pantera\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TherapieApp\src\be\pantera\TherapieApp\RegisterPage.java:26: error: package java.util.regex does not exist import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

--EDIT--
Seems this problem is related to codenameone so i changed the title. Thank you to those who answered before the edit. I didn't think the problem could be related to Codenameone, my apologies.

Comment: you are writing it like this? : import java.util.regex.*;

Comment: How are you building outside Netbeans? (If you say it gives no errors when compiling within Netbeans...)

Comment: How are you importing from that package? Please show us the code.

Comment: @Jon: i mean netbeans gives no red lines when coding, only gives the error when trying to build.

Comment: Is there any part in Netbeans where you specificy which version of the JDK you want to build against?

Comment: @Jon: yes there is an option to select the JDK you want to use. I have tried to make a quick standalone version of the mailcheck and this gave no problems so i think it's related to codenameone (in which i make my app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codename One doesn't support that package nor many other packages in the Java SE stack. Java SE is too big for mobile, our current hello world for iOS is 3mb and if we supported the full Java SE it would be around 18mb. The same is true for Windows Phone, RIM etc.

There are several solutions including a port of a [3rd party regex cn1lib](http://www.codenameone.com/cn1libs.html).

You can see the classes supported by Codename One in the JavaDocs: https://codenameone.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CodenameOne/javadoc/index.html

Comment: Thank you very much! Didn't know it didn't support all but how u explain it it's pretty obvious why.